# Estimated use of condom over time and it's effectiveness on HIV?

Tags: data-request, medical, disease

I'm looking for data to compare the use of condom among people (percentages) over time, and then in the same place and the same time, the number of people infected with HIV.

What I need exactly:

- The number of people in one given population (or globally).
- The number of them infected with HIV (or other STDs).
- The use of condoms during the same period in this population.
- If possible, I want to see the outbreak of the disease.

I don't really care about which population, it's just for testing an epidemiologic model.